# How to drop materialized views using EXECUTE statement in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic-sql, postgresql-9.3, materialized-views

My database is PostgreSQL (9.3.5).

We have more than 500 materialized views and want to drop some of them.
For that we are fetching from those materialized views from `pg_class`:

```
FOR MVNAME IN (SELECT relname
            FROM pg_class
            WHERE relkind='m')

LOOP
   EXECUTE 'DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW '||MVNAME||'';
END LOOP;
```

At executing time it's giving us an error:

> ```
> ERROR: "dimension" is not a materialized view
> SQL state: 42809
>
> Hint: Use DROP FOREIGN TABLE to remove a foreign table.
> Context: SQL statement "DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW dimension"
> PL/pgSQL function test_drop_dims() line 14 at EXECUTE statement
> ```

We can drop one materialized view using:

```
DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW MVNAME;
```

But we can't drop multiple materialized views using `EXECUTE` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message indicates that you have non-standard names created with double-quoting, like `"Dimension"` (mixed case). You need to **quote and escape identifiers properly** in dynamic SQL. Not only because it doesn't work any other way, also to avoid **SQL injection**.
Plus, you may have to **schema-qualify** names. Details:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

Also, you could [drop multiple MV's at once](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-dropmaterializedview.html) and don't need a loop this way:

```
EXECUTE (
   SELECT 'DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW ' || string_agg(oid::regclass::text, ', ')
   FROM   pg_class
   WHERE  relkind = 'm'
   );
```

**Careful with this!** It drops *all* materialized views in *all* schemas of your current database. You may want to double-check first.

Note how I am using `oid::regclass::text`, not `quote_ident(relname)`. That also covers the schema name automatically. [Detailed explantaion in the provided link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: If you execute a statement `DROP TABLE dimension` or `DROP TABLE Dimension` (same thing), how would the system know you really meant `"Dimension"` or `"diMenSion"`? The error message reports what you entered, folded to lower-case unless double-quoted, that's all. See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/4009